# Node GUnzip header mismatch when deflating

Tags: node.js, gunzip

I'm trying to deflate a gzip archive, locally created on macOS like:

```
$ echo "TEST" >> test.txt
$ echo "TEST" >> test.txt
$ echo "TEST" >> test.txt
$ echo "TEST" >> test.txt
$ tar -cvzf test.gz test.txt
```

then in node I open a input read stream, pipe the gunzip and write back to a output stream like:

```
$ node
> fs=require('fs'),gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
> fs.createReadStream( './test.gz'  ).pipe(gunzip).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./out.txt'))
```

What I get is a corrupted file having a bad header (that is the tar header actually - see response) that is:

```
]$ cat out.txt 
out.txt000644 000765 000024 00000024000 13070721621 014300 0ustar00loretoparisistaff000000 000000 out.txt000644 000765 000024 00000000036 13070720161 014301 0ustar00loretoparisistaff000000 000000 TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
```

**NOTE**:
I have explicitly omitted the `close` and `error` events, in that case it would be:

```
> fs.createReadStream( './test.gz'  ).pipe(gunzip).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./out.txt')).on('close', () => { console.log('done'); }).on('error', (error) => { console.error(error) });
```

but this does not affect this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bad header, that's a [tar header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)). Which exists because you're actually creating a gzipped tar file.

If you just want to compress `test.txt`, use this:

```
gzip < test.txt > test.gz
```

Comment: That's true. So what happens is that in `node` the deflate does not remove the tar header in the deflated file for some reason(?)

Comment: It's not supposed to remove the tar header, it's supposed to decompress the file, which it does. What's _in_ the decompressed data (i.e. a tar file) is not of its concern. If you want to handle that tar file, you need a module like [`tar`](https://github.com/npm/node-tar) to subsequently process the data.

Comment: btw, this was due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210135/node-download-archives-from-s3-error-incorrect-header-check-in-gunzip